# Why can't I access the Object in my function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function that detects motion between two frames and stores a cropped image of only the moving Object in the variable **cv::Mat result_cropped**. Now I want to add a function that checks the result_cropped for black pixels. I  wrote the code for that easely but I'm completly stuck on trying to implement it in my class.

For some reason my blackDetection(Mat & cropped) can't access the cropped image which results in the program crashing.
Heres my simplified code:

```
void ActualRec::run(){

    while (isActive){

    //...code to check for motion
    //if there was motion a cropped image will be stored in result_cropped      
        number_of_changes = detectMotion(motion, result, result_cropped, region,  max_deviation, color);

        if(number_of_changes>=there_is_motion) {
            if(number_of_sequence>0){
            // there was motion detected, store cropped image - this works 
            saveImg(pathnameThresh, result_cropped);

                if (blackDetection(result_cropped)==true){
                    //the cropped image has black pixels
                }
                else {
                   //the cropped image has no black pixels

            }
            number_of_sequence++;
        }
        else
        {
            // no motion was detected
        }
    }
}

bool ActualRec::blackDetection(Mat & result_cropped){
//...check for black pixels, program crashes since result_cropped is empty
//if i add imshow("test",result_cropped) I keep getting an empty window
   if (blackPixelCounter>0){
       return true;
   }
else return false;
}
```

Again, the problem is that I can't manage to access result_cropped in blackDetection(Mat & result_cropped).

\\edit: my complete code for this class http://pastebin.com/3i0WdLG0 . Please someone help me. This problem doesn't make any sense for me..

Comment: Can you correctly `imshow("test",result_cropped)` before and after `saveImg()`?  Get the OpenCV Image Watch plugin for Visual studio http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html, and then use the debugger

Comment: yes I can display the cropped image without any problem in my ActualRec::run and ActualRec::saveImg function. But it just won't work in the ActualRec::blackDetection function. I'm not using Visual Studio but I updated my post with the code for my whole class if that helps

Comment: Nevertheless you need to step through with a debugger to find the place that the contents of result_cropped disappear.  You don't have a waitkey() in blackDetection, so you will crash before you get to the waitkey in run() -- so maybe you are jumping to conclusions that result_cropped is "empty".  I can't see that you allocate croppedBlack anywhere, so you will crash on `croppedBlack.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =`.  BTW you image scanning loop blackDetection() is slower than it needs to be - don't use at<>(). Also you are mixing the C and C++ API.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I allocated croppedBlack and it worked. What I don't understand is why `imshow("test",result_cropped)` was giving me a blank image. It got called before anything related to croppedBlack. Anyway, thanks a ton for your help! I was really clueless there. //edit: how would I speed up the scanning loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `cv::waitKey()` in `blackDetection()`, so you will crash before you get to the `cvWaitKey()` in `run()`. You are jumping to conclusions that `result_cropped` is "empty".

You have not allocated `croppedBlack` anywhere, so you will crash on `croppedBlack.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =`.

Add this at the start of `blackDetection()` (e.g.):

```
croppedBlack.create(result_cropped.size(), result_cropped.type());
```

To make it faster see [How to scan images ... with OpenCV : The efficient way](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way)

```
bool ActualRec::blackDetection(Mat& result_cropped)
{
    croppedBlack.create(result_cropped.size(), result_cropped.type());

    int blackCounter = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < result_cropped.rows; ++y)
    {
        Vec3b* croppedBlack_row = croppedBlack.ptr<Vec3b>(y);
        Vec3b* result_cropped_row = result_cropped.ptr<Vec3b>(y);

        for(int x = 0; x < result_cropped.cols; ++x)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; ++c)
            {
               croppedBlack_row[x][c] = 
                    saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * result_cropped_row[x][c] + beta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```